# How to export libraries with components in CMAKE?

Tags: c++, cmake, export, libraries

I have tried finding this information on the official CMAKE wiki as well as searching SO (currently waiting for boost to download so I can wade through the source looking for how they do it). I was hoping someone here may be able to help with how this is done, or point me in the right direction to the answers!

I have a project that has several components. Right now, the project has subdirectories for libraries, and for applications. I am attempting to refactor the project and have applications in individual repositories and have the libraries exported.

How do other projects make it possible to use the following command (specifically, specifying which components):

FIND_PACKAGE (Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system date_time filesystem)

I would like to use the same system for my own project:

FIND_PACKAGE (Project REQUIRED COMPONENTS view gui execution analysis)

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know this question was long ago, but if you found a solution, could you share how exactly you did it?

Comment: @GeorgP. Unfortunately I don't think I ever followed-through with a solution. I just checked the project that this question was raised for, and the project still simply uses "add_subdirectory" commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good guide on how to write finders you may find in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules) (old CMake packages for popular distros had `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/readme.txt` file, but it seems nowadays it's absent or doesn't have any helpful info anymore ;-). Particularly it explains how to write a **correct** module w/ supporting "standard" syntax (`REQUIRE`, `COMPONENTS` & etc) using `find_package_handle_standard_args`. This is applicable for non-CMake-based packages and turns the [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) into *module mode*.

For CMake-based projects, there is a better (native) way to [export targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#exporting-targets) (aka *config mode* of the `find_package`). The modern CMake can help you to generate the needed `*.cmake` files, and your project ought to `install()` 'em into a proper location. So, dependent projects could use `find_package()` to *import* your targets (libraries or executables).

Comment: That readme file is just a pointer to the cmake-developer(7) manual page. And there I didn't find information on how to create components. Could you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: According to the cmake docs, find_package_handle_standard_args is used in Find modules, not in config modules as the question implies
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html

Comment: Can you update this with an explanation, which handles CMake Configs, not Modules (find). Will give an upvote then.

Comment: @FabianKeßler done

Answer (score -1):

How to find packages, and also how to write your own find modules is described here:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries

here is a very simple find module of mine. It´s located in the top dir where all my librarys are located, so in this case finding the correct paths is rather trivial.

```
# AsmjitConfig.cmake
# - Config file for the Asmjit package
# sets:
# Asmjit_FOUND
# Asmjit_INCLUDE_DIR
# Asmjit_LIBRARIES

set(Asmjit_FOUND FALSE)

find_library(Asmjit_LIBRARY NAMES asmjit HINTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/asmjit)
find_path(Asmjit_INCLUDE_DIR asmjit/asmjit.h HINTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/asmjit/src)

message(STATUS "${Asmjit_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "${Asmjit_LIBRARY}")

if(NOT Asmjit_LIBRARY OR NOT Asmjit_INCLUDE_DIR)
    set(Asmjit_FOUND FALSE)
else()
    set(Asmjit_FOUND TRUE)
endif()
```

in your CMakeLists.txt tell cmake where it can find your modules:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "path/to/librarys")
```

after that find_package should work just fine.

Comment: How does this answer the question?