# How to configure project with COMPONENTS in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, components

I want to create a project of projects using cmake which is accessible in a similar manner to that used by Poco. I find that using Poco as an example is crowded and difficult to follow so I am trying to create a minimal version, without macros so that I can see what is going on. I have constructed a repository for this example here.

https://github.com/markeastwood82/nomnoms

This, and what is written below is currently my best guess at how to solve this problem after some days of reading up / grappling with "modern CMake", except that it doesn't quite work. Essentially I have a library `noms` with components `fruit` and `veg` which I want link dynamically from an application `munch`. I can install the `noms` library, but cannot find it with `munch`. Can someone please help me to put this thing together?

The two projects are structured are as follows:

```
noms
|---- CMakeLists.txt
+---- fruit
|     |---- CMakeLists.txt
|     |---- fruit-config.cmake.in
|     +---- src
|     |     |----apple.cpp
|     |
|     +---- include/noms/fruit
|           |----apple.h
|
+---- veg
      |---- CMakeLists.txt
      |---- veg-config.cmake.in
      +---- src
      |     |---- asparagus.cpp
      |
      +---- include/noms/veg
            |---- asparagus.h
```

```
munch
|---- CmakeLists.txt
+---- src
      |---- main.cpp
```

The file `noms/CMakeLists.txt` contains the following.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(project noms)
set(version 1.0.0)

project(${project})

add_subdirectory(fruit)
add_subdirectory(veg)

# UPDATE: implement advice from Tsyvarev

configure_file(${project}-config.cmake
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${project}-config.cmake"
  @ONLY
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${project}-config-version.cmake"
  VERSION ${version}
  COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

install(
  FILES
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${project}-config.cmake"
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/${project}
)
```

The file `noms/fruit/CMakeLists.txt` (and almost identical for `noms/veg/CMakeLists.txt`) is

```
set(component fruit)

add_library(${component} SHARED src/apple.cpp)

# namespaced alias
add_library(${project}::${component} ALIAS ${component})

target_include_directories(${component}
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

install(TARGETS ${component} EXPORT ${component}-targets
  COMPONENT ${component}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

install(EXPORT ${component}-targets
  FILE "${project}-${component}-targets.cmake"
  NAMESPACE ${project}::
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/${project}
  COMPONENT ${component}
)

# This seems like a kludge, but it does place the file in the correct location
# on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04). Idea taken from Poco
configure_file("${component}-config.cmake.in"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${project}-${component}-config.cmake"
  @ONLY
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${project}-${component}-config-version.cmake"
  VERSION ${version}
  COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

install(
  FILES
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${project}-${component}-config.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${project}-${component}-config-version.cmake"
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/${project}
  COMPONENT ${component}
)

# DESTINATION will be automatically prefixed by ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
install(
  DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  COMPONENT ${component}
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)
```

Finally, the file for `noms/fruit/fruit-config.cmake.in` (and almost identical for `noms/veg/veg-config.cmake`) is

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/noms-fruit-config-version.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/noms-fruit-config-targets.cmake)
```

For project `munch`, the file `munch/CMakeLists.txt` is simply

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(project munch)

find_package(noms REQUIRED COMPONENTS fruit)

add_executable(${project} src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${project}
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:$include>
)

target_link_libraries(${project}
  PUBLIC
    noms::fruit
)
```

After installing `noms` I try to build `munch`, however cmake can't find the `noms-config.cmake` file. I don't know what it should contain, nor where I should really put it. I am also not sure it the method of using `configure_file` in `noms/<food-type>/CMakeLists.txt` is appropriate, given this does not seem to be required in the example here

https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2017/blob/master/05-19-2017_friday/effective_cmake__daniel_pfeifer__cppnow_05-19-2017.pdf

My question is essentially the same as was asked here, which is currently unanswered (the accepted answer is incorrect, as I have commented in that thread). Actually to be fair, since that thread is 6 years old, it may have been correct at the time of writing, but does not appear to utilize the xxx-config.cmake method that is now recommended.

[How to export libraries with components in CMAKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976594/how-to-export-libraries-with-components-in-cmake)

Please feel free to pull me up on any mistakes I have made, or anything that could be done better. Thanks

*** UPDATE ***

In addition to the updated `noms/CMakeLists.txt` file above, I have implemented the following `noms/noms-config.cmake` file as per advice from @Tsyvarev below ...

```
foreach(component ${noms_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/noms-${component}-config.cmake)
endforeach()
```

The resulting code now works, thankyou!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CMake doesn't process `COMPONENTS` list automatically. It leaves that mission to `noms-config.cmake` script, which is searched and executed when one issues the command

```
find_package(noms COMPONENTS fruit veg)
```

From the [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html) documentation:

> In Config mode `find_package` handles `REQUIRED`, `QUIET`, and `[version]` options automatically but leaves it to the package configuration file to handle components in a way that makes sense for the package.

Inside this config file, you may extract list of requested components (given via `COMPONENTS` option to `find_package()`) from the `noms_FIND_COMPONENTS` variable, and perform appropriate actions. For example:

**noms-config.cmake**:

```
foreach(component ${noms_FIND_COMPONENTS})
  # For requested component, execute its "config" script
  include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${component}-config.cmake)
endforeach()
```

This implies, that you will install the script `noms-config.cmake` to `lib/cmake/noms` subdirectory, near the other `.cmake` scripts you have already installed in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've implemented your suggestion and edited the question code and repo. When I install, the process no longer complains about the missing noms-config.cmake file, but is does give me the following error...

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_executable):
  Target "munch" links to target "noms::fruit" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?

Comment: It was a wrong name of the variable `noms_FIND_COMPONENTS`, sorry. The answer post is fixed now.

Comment: That was the key change that made this code work. Thankyou for your help!

Comment: Is this really the easiest way to handle a component-list based CMake project? CMAKE files seem to be very verbose, e.g., for similar components (fruit/veg) the CMakeLists.txt and the .in files are almost identical. I'm facing a similar situation where modules/components are always part of a folder but not all of them must be selected per project (deleting unused components isn't possible).