# How to create cmake project with components

Tags: cmake

Im trying to create project in Cmake which contains components.
So another project can use this project using:

```
find_package(ltk COMPONENTS Core Networking REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(test ltk::Core ltk::Networking)
```

#### My library project (called ltk)

Here is a project tree:

```
ltk/
|--- CMakeLists.txt
|--- ltkConfig.cmake.in
|--- ltkConfigVersion.cmake.in
|
+--- Core/
|    |--- core.cc 
|    |--- core.h
|    |--- CMakeLists.txt
|
+--- Networking/
     |--- networking.cc
     |--- networking.h
     |--- CMakeLists.txt
```

Full project is here: https://gitlab.com/T0maas/cmake-testing

The file `ltk/CMakeLists.txt` has this content:

```
set(project ltk)
set(LTK_VERSION 0.0.1)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(${project})
add_subdirectory(Core)
add_subdirectory(Networking)

foreach(p LIB BIN INCLUDE CMAKE)
  set(var INSTALL_${p}_DIR)
  if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${${var}}")
    set(${var} "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${${var}}")
  endif()
endforeach()


export(TARGETS Core Networking FILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ltkTargets.cmake")
export(PACKAGE ltk)

file(RELATIVE_PATH REL_INCLUDE_DIR "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}" "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}")

set(CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

configure_file(ltkConfig.cmake.in "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ltkConfig.cmake" @ONLY)
set(CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS "\${LTK_CMAKE_DIR}/${REL_INCLUDE_DIR}")

configure_file(ltkConfig.cmake.in   "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/ltkConfig.cmake" @ONLY)

configure_file(ltkConfigVersion.cmake.in  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ltkConfigVersion.cmake" @ONLY)

install(FILES
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/ltkConfig.cmake"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/ltkConfigVersion.cmake"
  DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/${project}" )

install(EXPORT ltkTargets DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/${project}" )
```

And the `Core/CMakeLists.txt` contains this:

```
set (component Core)
add_library(${component} SHARED core.cc )
add_library(${project}::${component} ALIAS ${component})

set_target_properties(${component} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER  "core.h")

install(TARGETS ${component} 
  EXPORT ltkTargets
  COMPONENT ${component}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/ltk
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/ltk
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/ltk/
)
```

The `Networking/CMakeLists.txt` is similar to `Core/CMakeLists.txt`

File `ltkConfig.cmake.in` contains this:

```
get_filename_component(LTK_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
set(LTK_INCLUDE_DIRS "@CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS@")


if(NOT TARGET Core AND NOT LTK_BINARY_DIR)
  include("${LTK_CMAKE_DIR}/ltkTargets.cmake")
endif()

if(NOT TARGET Networking AND NOT LTK_BINARY_DIR)
  include("${LTK_CMAKE_DIR}/ltkTargets.cmake")
endif()

set(LTK_LIBRARIES Core Networking)
```

And the `ltkConfigVersion.cmake.in`:

```
set(PACKAGE_VERSION "@LTK_VERSION@")

# Check whether the requested PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION is compatible
if("${PACKAGE_VERSION}" VERSION_LESS "${PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION}")
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE FALSE)
else()
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
  if ("${PACKAGE_VERSION}" VERSION_EQUAL "${PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION}")
    set(PACKAGE_VERSION_EXACT TRUE)
  endif()
endif()
```

After install this project I see some files in `/usr/lib/cmake/ltk`:

```
ltkTargets-noconfig.cmake
ltkTargets.cmake
ltkConfigVersion.cmake
ltkConfig.cmake
```

#### Testing

But now when I try to configure some testing project, which has following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test)
find_package(ltk COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
add_executable(main main.cc)
target_link_libraries(main ltk::Core)
```

It shows following errors:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (add_executable):
  Target "main" links to target "ltk::Core" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?


-- Generating done
```

I've read following links, but this doesn't helped me:

- https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file
- [How to configure project with COMPONENTS in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54702582/how-to-configure-project-with-components-in-cmake)

## Edit

Now I added `NAMESPACE ltk::` `to install(EXPORT)` in `ltk/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
install(EXPORT ltkTargets DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/${project}" NAMESPACE ltk::)
```

But the testing project which contains `#include <core.h>` complains:

```
fatal error: core.h: No such file or directory
```

Path to `/usr/include/ltk` has not been exported.

## Edit 2

Fixed include problems with:
Added to {Core, Networking}/CMakeLists.txt

```
target_include_directories(${component} PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/ltk>)
```

Now I can use in my testing project this:

```
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC ltk)
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to pass `NAMESPACE ltk::` option to the `install(EXPORT)` command call. Exactly this options provides prefix for the imported targets.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks that partially solved my problem, but now I have problem with include directories. Testing project which has `#include <core.h>` complains that can't find core.h file.

Comment: Hmm, the whole wiki your refer to seems to describe "pre-modern" CMake, before IMPORTED targets have all their capabilities. E.g. their config file uses `set(FOOBAR_INCLUDE_DIRS "@CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS@")` for tell the user about include directories. In "modern" CMake include directories could be specified alongside with the target, using `target_include_directories` call. The modern way for packaging is described in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html), I would suggest to follow it instead the wiki you refer to.

Comment: This question/answer would be much easier to read if syntax highlighting were used for the CMake code snippets. I would edit it myself but the edit queue is full...

Comment: I added ```cmake to markdown codeblock, but highlighting still does not work.